# group all the connections in a dataset R

Tags: r

I would like to group the territories to the larger unit with respect to the fusions/divisions happening trough time.

Here below a replicable example:

```r
data<-data.frame(id_territory=c("id_1", "id_2", "id_3","id_3","id_4","id_5","id_6","id_7", "id_8", "id_9"), type_mutation=c("absorbed territory","absorbed territory", "absorbing territory", "absorbed territory", "absorbing territory", "absorbing territory","creation","part of territory transferred", "absorbed territory", "absorbing territory"), id_reform =c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D"))
```

The data can be interpreted as follow: Territory 1 and 2 were absorbed by territory 3 during reform A. Territory 3 was then divided in territory 4 and 5 during reform B. During reform C, a territory 6 has been created with a part of territory 7.

I would like to group the territories, in order to take into account all the modifications. The wanted output would be:

```r
df<-data.frame(id_territory=c("id_1", "id_2", "id_3","id_3","id_4","id_5","id_6","id_7", "id_8", "id_9"), type_mutation=c("absorbed territory","absorbed territory", "absorbing territory", "absorbed territory", "absorbing territory", "absorbing territory","creation","part of territory transferred", "absorbed territory", "absorbing territory"), id_reform =c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D"), group_id=c("group_1","group_1", "group_1", "group_1","group_1","group_1","group_2","group_2", "group_3", "group_3"))
```

I can't find a way to obtain such output,

Thank very much for your help,

Comment: It's not clear from your example what indicates when a new group is formed. Do you just want to change the group when a "creation" even is found? Are you assuming these events are ordered somehow? What exactly does the `id_modifcations` column mean>

Comment: Sorry for that, id_modifications is an id for the event, so the absorption of territory 1, 2 by the territory 3 are part of one reform. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you want to group *absorb* vs not *absorb*?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Not really, I need to group the territories that have been connected to each other trough division/fusion. If a territory is not absorbed or is not absorbing anything it is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To make your `data` to `df` you can use `case_when` as follows:

```
df <- data|>
  mutate(group_id = case_when(
  type_mutation == "absorbed territory"  ~ "group_1",
  type_mutation == "absorbing territory" ~ "group_1",
  TRUE ~ "group_2"))
```

Comment: You are right in my previous example it would have work. However in the real datasets not all territories are connected, hence I will have more than two groups. I edited the example. I am sorry it was not very clear.

Comment: I think you have to use `case_when` with multiple conditions instead of one as I was doing above.